# How to retrieve LASTEST emails from a POP3 Server?

Tags: vb.net, pop3

I was recently working on a project that involving connection to a POP3 Server. I was using this piece of C# from CodeProject(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6062/A-POP3-Client-in-C-NET), had complied it into a DLL and was using it in VB.NET.

I'd connected to my Hotmail Account (not many mails) and it seems to work just fine. After that, I connected to my GMail account... I started seeing errors!

POP3 is meant to fetch emails only from the Inbox. Even when I made my own program to cross-check the problem, I saw that when I requested for the number of messages, the GMail POP3 Server returned a value which is about 5 times less than the actual inbox size.

[image]

255 Emails in my Inbox?? Online it shows me 2,414 emails in my Inbox.
And secondly, my MAIN QUESTION is that how does one fetch the LATEST email from the POP3 Mailbox. What I've fetched here was an e-mail with ID 1! I want to fetch the top 20 emails (that were most recently delivered to the account)...

Is there any work around for how to fetch the LATEST email from the POP3 Server rather than the oldest emails? I've also tried to connect to the Hotmail POP3 Mail Server. Again a "RETR 1" command fetches me the oldest email and not the latest one! Any known work-around?

Comment: Well if Item 1 is the oldest.. take a wild guess at where the newest will be.

Comment: I'd file a support request with gmail and ask if their pop3 server can deal with more than 255 emails in a single session.

Comment: @Boo I understand that if 1 is the oldest, the (total number of emails in the box)th mail will be the latest. But the mailbox size it reflects is 255. So even if I fetch the 255th email, that is not the latest one in the whole inbox, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I think your question is answered here: "Incorrect message count using STAT command" http://groups.google.com/group/Gmail-Help-POP-and-IMAP-en/browse_thread/thread/8be2c0b2bf383c15/7c57310cd5b11fc9?pli=1</strike>

[Update on 2016-06-30: The above link will not necessarily work, demonstrating why link-only answers are frowned upon so...]

The messages are made available in batches. After retrieving a batch, re-connect to get the next batch. Repeat as required.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your support. But the thread doesn't seem to give me the right solution! It says that fetch the batch of UIDs you get and sign off the server. After you reconnect and request for UIDs, you will end up getting a new batch of them hence continuing the list of UIDs. But when I put in the command after signing off the server and  re-logging in, I saw that the server dumped back the SAME LIST OF UIDs. Any work-around??

Comment: I think you have to RETR the messages before signing off and on again. You will have to test it. Otherwise, you might want to use the IMAP interface.

Comment: Hey! I tried that out too... But no luck man! Anyways, thanks for your help. I'll give you an upvote for an attempt to help me :)
Please let me know if you ever find a working solution for this GMail POP3 Server problem

Comment: Also note that RETR in general case does not imply DELEtion of a message, however server may implement some kind of "download once" policy — in which case it becomes true. So, according to RFC1939, UA (user agent) MUST issue DELE command followed by successful QUIT to ensure that a the message won't appear on the LIST ever again.

Comment: According to my experiments on Yandex and Gmail POP3 servers, DELE command effectively marks messages as read but not actually deletes them from the servers. Precise behavior may be configured through web interface.

Answer (score 0):

in AUTH, instead of using:

```
USER foo@gmail.com
```

use:

```
USER recent:foo@gmail.com
```

Answer (score -3):

instead of using pop3 u can use imap ptotocol to retrive all mails from GMAIL inbox.

Comment: it is definitely true that IMAP4 is an alternative to POP3, and much more complicated protocol. but the question is all about peculiarities of POP3 implementation, so why bother suggesting something unrelated?